# Listener to identify exact change on files (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse-rcp, listener

I'm creating a simple Eclipse plugin in which I'm modifying an XML file using an editor, in this editor I have two buttons to add and remove entries in the XML file, and I need to identify the exact code generated by the editor (which XML entries where added/removed since the last time the file was saved).

I was exploring the **IResourceChangeEvent** and **ResourceDelta** class but it only let you know if the file was modified or not, but not the actual change. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As you already mention, the workspace sends `IResourceChangeEvent`s only after a resource was written. To get deltas you have to track the content yourself.

The workspace keeps a *local history* of files. You may want to look into `IFileHistory` and `IFile#getHistory()` to see if this is suitable for your needs.